# Can not download file from Google Sheets sidebar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

We have a Google Sheets Add-on that creates a 3D view (via BabylonJS) in an IFRAME  the sidebar.
One of the things you can do with the 3D view is to store it into a GLB file, that can be downloaded (and emailed).
Creating that 3D view works, but downloading the 3D the GLB file does not work.

```
GLTF2Export.GLBAsync(this.scene, "packScene.glb").then((glb) => {
            console.log("File created");
            glb.downloadFiles();
            console.log("File downloaded");
            if (glbDone) {
                glbDone();
                }
            });
        }
```

I see all console messages, but the file is not downloaded.

We use exactly the same code in our Microsoft Excel Add-In, where it works as expected.

The Sheets provided IFRAME seems to miss the sandbox allow-download setting.

What is missing here?

Comment: There isn't much we can do  without [mcve]

Comment: Speculating, If the download is automatic, make sure you have all the required sandbox attributes in your iframe. If that's the case, Consider changing the download to require user action like click.

Comment: Probably related https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/157368720

Comment: Creating that minimal eampe is quite complicated. But we use the exactly same code in Google Sheets and Microsoft Excel Online. It seems that the Excel provided iframe (hosting our sidebar (named TaskPane in Excel)  has sandbox=".. allow-downloads" while the Sheets provided iframes (id=sandboxFrame and userHtmlFrame) do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, this issue seems to be already reported and tracked down by google in [this post](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/157368720).

There is not much that we can do here to help you.

Comment: I have starred the issue there and hope for a quick fix.